# How to set criteria for NHibernate for MySQL MD5?

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, md5

In MySQL i can do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MD5(column) = 'blablabla';
```

But how do i do that with NHibernate and Criteria functions?

I got a value alrady as md5 but the column in the database is not md5 hashed...

I working in C#.

Some ideas?

Comment: I hope that unhashed data is not your user's password :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you can use Expression.Sql, the same should work in C#, something like:

```
var table = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Table))
            .Add(Expression.Sql("MD5(column)= ?", value, NHibernateUtil.String))
            .UniqueResult<Table>();
```

where `value` is the [hex-encoded](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5) value of your MD5 hash.

Although, one word of caution - if the value stored in the database is the user's password, then your design is flawed and insecure. You should only store salted, hashed passwords in the database. No, you shouldn't even do that, you should right away use [bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/), scrypt or PBKDF2 for that.

Comment: No no no, its not the user password, its going to be used on a PRIMARY KEY that we going to send in a URL, so we dont whant the users to try other keys.